# how to content of child div next to parent div with no space gap

Tags: php, jquery, css

```js
function ClickParent(ClickElem,ElemFind)
 { 
  $("."+ClickElem).click(function() {
   var GetGrp = $(this).parents(".group");
   GetGrp.find("."+ElemFind).fadeToggle();
  }); 
 }
 
// Find one level
ClickParent('name','moreinfo');
// Find another level
ClickParent('moreinfo','evenmore');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
 I am 
 <a href="#" class="name" style="color:black;">How are you?</a>
 <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
  Fine
 </div>
 <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
  Even more stuff.
 </div>
</div>
```

How to show content of moreinfo class next to group class with no space gap.so if more content is there then they show as like passage. how to achive it?

  -

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `div` is a block element, so try span instead

```js
function ClickParent(ClickElem, ElemFind) {
  $("." + ClickElem).click(function() {
    var GetGrp = $(this).parents(".group");
    GetGrp.find("." + ElemFind).fadeToggle();
  });
}

// Find one level
ClickParent('name', 'moreinfo');
// Find another level
ClickParent('moreinfo', 'evenmore');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  I am
  <a href="#" class="name" style="color:black;">How are you?</a>
  <span class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
    Fine
  </span>
  <span class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
    Even more stuff.
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: still answer is same.

Comment: how to make span display inline when click on How are you?